# Error while saving into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, crud

I have created a player selector for a fantasy football project. Now when I am trying to save the team, it just rollsback the commit.

HTML code for the team is:

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>

                        <center><h3>Choose your squad</h3></center>
                        <div class="col l5 offset-l1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field">
                                    <%= f.label :name %>
                                    <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, :class => "validate", :placeholder => "Enter a name for your Team", :style => "width: 86%;" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="playerCounter">
                                    <div class="col l6">
                                        <span id="playersAdded" >0</span>/<span id="totalPlayers" ></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="hidden">
                                        <%= f.text_field :gk1_id, :id=>'contestEntry_goalkeeper1',  :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :gk2_id, :id=>"contestEntry_goalkeeper2", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :def1_id, :id=>"contestEntry_defender1", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :def2_id, :id=>"contestEntry_defender2" , :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :def3_id, :id=>"contestEntry_defender3", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :def4_id, :id=>"contestEntry_defender4", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :def5_id, :id=>"contestEntry_defender5", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :mid1_id, :id=>"contestEntry_midfielder1", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :mid2_id, :id=>"contestEntry_midfielder2", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :mid3_id, :id=>"contestEntry_midfielder3", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :mid4_id, :id=>"contestEntry_midfielder4", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :mid5_id, :id=>"contestEntry_midfielder5", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :fwd1_id, :id=>"contestEntry_forward1", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :fwd2_id, :id=>"contestEntry_forward2", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                        <%= f.text_field :fwd3_id, :id=>"contestEntry_forward3", :class=>"form-control" %>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="save-btn">
                                        <div class="col l6">
                                            <%= f.submit 'Save', :class =>"waves-effect waves-light btn orange accent-4"  %> 

                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                            <div class="col l3">
                                <span>Remaining Salary</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col l3">
                                <span id="salaryLeft" >100,000</span>
                            </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
```

My controller code:

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
    layout 'teams'

  def index

    @players = Player.all


  end

  def create
    @players = Player.all
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    if @team.save
      redirect_to :index
      flash[:notice] = "Team created successfully."
    else
      puts "error"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @players = Player.all
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def edit
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])

    if @team.update_attibutes(team_params)
      redirect_to :index
      flash[:notice] = "Team updated successfully."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def team_params

    params.require(:team).permit(:name, :gk1_id, :gk2_id, :def1_id, :def2_id, :def3_id, :def4_id, :def5_id, :mid1_id, :mid2_id, :mid3_id, :mid4_id, :mid5_id, :fwd1_id, :fwd2_id, :fwd3_id, :user_id)

  end
end
```

Also the console isn't displaying any error. My console log:

```
Started POST "/teams" for ::1 at 2016-08-17 04:51:59 +0530
Processing by TeamsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UU/L+RJgtQQQFy8o/bl8xucbPKGD6qTVfHPBCvsZIXx/VtRzm5zyPr24T0kdIcAXobO/gBpWNmY9G+pmKd3G8g==", "team"=>{"name"=>"Test Team", "gk1_id"=>"1", "gk2_id"=>"2", "def1_id"=>"5", "def2_id"=>"6", "def3_id"=>"7", "def4_id"=>"8", "def5_id"=>"9", "mid1_id"=>"26", "mid2_id"=>"20", "mid3_id"=>"19", "mid4_id"=>"18", "mid5_id"=>"17", "fwd1_id"=>"25", "fwd2_id"=>"24", "fwd3_id"=>"23"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Player Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 26 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 20 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 19 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 18 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 17 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 25 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 24 LIMIT 1
  Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 23 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
error
  Rendering teams/new.html.erb within layouts/teams
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_new.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (9.6ms)
  Player Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players`
  Rendered teams/new.html.erb within layouts/teams (26.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 38.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)
```

I just can't understand the problem. Everything seems to be working, it is taking the correct values, database is connected trying to save but just isn't saving.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance. Also, I am quite new with ROR so any help in improving the code would also be greatly appreciated.

After Edit

Ok Now I changed the @team.save to @team.save!. It shows an error Validation failed: User must exist.

And the console shows

```
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 96ms (ActiveRecord: 7.2ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: User must exist):

app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:16:in `create'
  Rendering /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (8.6ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (117.3ms)
```

My team.rb code:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :players
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :gk1, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :gk2, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :def1, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :def2, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :def3, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :def4, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :def5, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :mid1, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :mid2, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :mid3, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :mid4, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :mid5, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :fwd1, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :fwd2, :class_name => 'Player'
    belongs_to :fwd3, :class_name => 'Player'
end
```

Comment: In your `teams_controller#create` method change `save` to `save!` and then re-run it. The interrobang form of save will throw an exception to your log so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @ravi, can you post the code in `team.rb`?

Comment: @MarsAtomic -  Done

Comment: you could update your puts statement to 'puts @team.errors.full_messages' just to get more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have the association where a `team` belongs to a `user`, and therefore your `team` object should have a `user_id` attribute.  however, when you try to save your `team` object in the create action in your teams controllers, there is no user associated with the team yet

Try doing the following in your teams controller:

```
 def create
    @players = Player.all
    @team = Team.new(team_params)
    @team.user_id = current_user.id

    if @team.save
      redirect_to :index
      flash[:notice] = "Team created successfully."
    else
      puts "error"
      render :new
    end
 end
```

Comment: Yeah thanx... I get it now

Answer (score 0):

You have a relationship between `user` and `teams` but you're creating a `team` record without associating it with a `user`. Modify your `create` action to create a team which is associated with a `user` record.

```
def create
  @players = Player.all
  @team = current_user.teams.new(team_params)

  if @team.save
    redirect_to :index
    flash[:notice] = "Team created successfully."
  else
    puts "error"
    render :new
  end
end
```

This way, when a `team` is saved, the `user_id` field is automatically populated with the `current_user`'s id.

Comment: Thanx a lot... I am using the players for a totally different thing... They don't need an availability feild... thanx anyways

Comment: @ravi, I misinterpreted. Updated the answer.